# A table shared by several

Tags: php, mysql, database

I use this often: For example

```
Addresses
--------
address_id
street
city
…
```

and

```
Users      Shops
-------    -------
user_id    shop_id
name       name
address_id address_id
…          …
```

where of course, address_id are foreign keys.

With constraints I can manage to delete (or update) associated users oder shops cascadingly, whenever I delete (or update) a shared address. I know.
I set to NULL.

I want to delete a shared address if and only if there is neither a shop nor a user associated with an address.

OR am I doing it wrong. What I do here, is to set the address as a parent of shop as well as of user. I do not see it this way. I take address as a child of both, user and shop. I maybe should do

```
Addresses
---------
address_id
…
shop_id
user_id
```

But I don't like that approach, because it seems too inflexible to me.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this. You can do it using triggers after deletes in the `Users` and `Shops` tables.

Comment: As long as you do not have ON DELETE CASCADE in your foreign key definitions for the shop and user tables, then you will not be able to delete the corresponding entries in the address table.

Comment: @Barmar Triggers are a fine idea. But besides that: Is that what I am doing against design rules or something?

Comment: Opinion-based questions like that are not a good fit for SO. This issue depends on the details of tha application. In some cases it's a waste of space to keep a master row if there are now dependents using it, but in others it makes sense to keep them so they can be used in the future.